# How to make the determinant formula visible even in cases when det=0

Tags: output-formatting, linear-algebra, display

When I compute the determinant analytically in *Mathematica*, I do it with

```
Det[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]
```

which gives the output

```
-b c + a d
```

I would like to see this formula even if the determinant is zero as

```
Det[{{a, b}, {-a, -b}}]
```

which yields the output

```
0
```

instead of something like

```
-b (-a) + a (-b)
```

This is just a small example, but my matrices are a little larger, and I need to figure out analytically why some determinants are zero and some are not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possibility is to temporarily inactivate the arithmetic operators, like so:

```
Block[{Times = Inactive[Times], Plus = Inactive[Plus]}, 
      Det[{{a, b}, {-a, -b}}]]
   a*(-1*b)+-1*b*(-1*a)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
m = {{a, b}, {-a, -b}};

Det[Map[ToBoxes, m, {2}]] // DisplayForm
(* -b (-a)+a (-b) *)
```